# Determining the Optimal Approach for Fine-tuning a Pre-trained Neural Network on Images of Varying Sizes

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, fine-tuning

In the context of fine-tuning a pre-trained neural network initially trained on 1024x1024 images, which method is more suitable for adapting a dataset containing images ranging from 320x120 to 320x320? Is it preferable to pad the smaller images with white pixels to convert them into 1024x1024 images, or should the images be resized to match the network's input size?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not aware of any best practice for this case (though there may be one for those better informed) I'd say that resizing is a lot more likely to give you good results. Zeroing out (or adding ones or whatever, the padding method makes nearly no difference after a couple of iterations since any constants will be equivalent to changing the bias one layer on) large portions of your input is going to mean that later layers have a much greater difference between the original image representation and the new one, which means it will probably take longer to converge back to good accuracy. Resizing images on the other hand is something that we do all the time when working with cnn's since most architectures require fixed sized input and lots of real datasources don't produce fixed sized images. If you resize you're basically just giving a blurry and possibly stretched image to the network. The network should adapt fairly easily to that modification.